# PostgreSQL - reverse order not strings

Tags: sql, postgresql

in psql
if a value is '03 0F 0E AB 0B 05 0E E4'

And I want it to be - E4 0E 05 0B AB 0E 0F 03
order is reversed but strings haven't.

is it possible?
The reverse function reverses it to ' 4E E0 50 B0 BA E0 F0 30

Comment: WTH are you using `EXECUTE` everywhere? There's nothing dynamic about these queries.

Comment: At my work place all the queries are Dynamic - hence I am asked to put everything in dynamic. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
select string_agg( unnest, ' ' order by ordinality desc) 
from unnest(regexp_split_to_array('03 0F 0E AB 0B 05 0E E4', ' ')) 
WITH ORDINALITY;
```